# Parse table details not having ID or a class name using JSOUP in JAVA

Tags: java, jsoup

I have two more than two tables in a web page.
They are given below:

1. `<table border="0" cellpadding="0"  cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; float : left">`
2. `<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" style="border-collapse : collapse">`
3. `<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse : collapse">`

I need to get the rows and columns of second table which doesn't contain any id or class name. How do i get its details using `doc.select();` method

Comment: is *two more than two* = 4?

Comment: two more than two tables = 4 tables, can you just say four?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table you want to get is always the second you can use ([demo](http://try.jsoup.org/~5susNw6udU6eWyValHlKMWB-StY)):

```
table:nth-of-type(2)
```

From the [documentation](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) of Jsoup selectors:

> *nth-of-type(an+b)* pseudo-class notation represents an element that has an+b-1 siblings with the same expanded element name before it in the document tree, for any zero or positive integer value of n, and has a parent element.

If it's not always the second you should find some attribute values that only your table has and use them in the selector. For example in your case it could be:

```
table[width=100%][border=0][cellspacing=1][cellpadding=2]
```

Comment: can you do the cssquery with doc.select();  method?

Comment: Of course, read the linked documentation, Jsoup is fantastic!